# reading a csv file into a dictionary of nested lists

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have  a CSV file of sat scores in the format:

State       Rate         Verbal           Math

and the corresponding values for all fifty states.  I need a dictionary. The dictionary format for data is the column names as the key and then data under each as lists of the values for that key.I am able to print the list out in the proper format but the lists are not linked to the keys in the dictionary and the dictionary is there, but empty. After many attempts at different methods, this is the best I've come up with:

```
with open('../sat_scores.csv', mode='r') as f:
    sat= {}                                          
    label_line =[]                                  
    reader = csv.reader(f)                           
    count = 0                                        
    for row in reader:                 
        print(row)
        if count == 0:                                
           for item in row:                           
               item = sat.keys                       
        count +=1                                  
    for row in reader:
        for key in sat.keys:                      
            for score in row:                     
                sat[key].append(score)
    print(sat)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What exactly does your data look like? Is there only one row per state? Can your csv have multiple rows for a state? What about missing data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your rows are unique, this should do it:

```
with open('../sat_scores.csv', mode='r') as f:
    sat = {}                                                                                        
    for row in csv.reader(f):                 
        sat[row[0]] = row[1:]
```

`row` is a list. `row[0]` has the name of your state. `row[1]`, `row[2]` and `row[3]` have everything else. You can use list slicing and make an entry of `State : <List of data>`.

And you're done. It would be good to know that `item = sat.keys` does not do what you expect. `keys` is a function of the dict, and you are assigning the *function* to a variable. Look at this:

```
>>> sat = {}
>>> sat.keys
<built-in method keys of dict object at 0x101b81c08>
```

What you should be doing is something along these lines:

```
>>> row = ['OH', '88%', 200, 180]
>>> sat[row[0]] = row[1:]
>>> sat
{'OH': ['88%', 200, 180]}
```

Comment: does your comment mean it would be items = keys  and then

Comment: No! You don't need an `item` variable at all :) When creating a key value pair, you must specify the key and value together.